Jenkins: Gradle unable to connect to MariaDB despite successful setup in Jenkins pipeline
(This is my first ever question, if anyone needs more info please comment)
This is for a school thing, but I've been utterly stuck on this problem for weeks and no-one I know seems to be able to solve this problem.
The pipeline is Terraform > Gitlab > Debian OS > Openstack > Jenkins
In my Jenkins pipeline, I've configured a Spring Boot application to connect to a MariaDB database. The jenkins logs say that the database creation and SQL queries were executed successfully during the build process. However, when the application attempts to connect to the MariaDB database using the specified credentials, it fails to establish a connection.
As this is a pipeline assignment, I can't proceed without the database as springboot pretty much fails all the tests.
Jenkins Success Log
Jenkins Error Log
This is my Jenkins build steps.
#!/usr/bin/bash

DB_HOST="localhost"
DB_USER="root"
DB_PASS="comsc"
DB_NAME="trailsdb"

#create db if db doesnt exist
mysql -h $DB_HOST -u $DB_USER -p$DB_PASS -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $DB_NAME;"

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Database created successfully. Proceeding with SQL queries."
else
    echo "Error selecting database. Exiting script."
    exit 1
fi

#schema
mysql -h $DB_HOST -u $DB_USER -p$DB_PASS $DB_NAME < src/main/resources/schema.sql

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "SQL queries executed successfully."
else
    echo "Error executing SQL queries."
    exit 1
fi

# data insertion
mysql -h $DB_HOST -u $DB_USER -p$DB_PASS $DB_NAME < src/main/resources/data.sql

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Data queries executed successfully."
else
    echo "Error executing data SQL queries."
    exit 1
fi

/opt/gradle/gradle-7.6/bin/gradle clean
/opt/gradle/gradle-7.6/bin/gradle build -x test
/opt/gradle/gradle-7.6/bin/gradle bootjar
/opt/gradle/gradle-7.6/bin/gradle jacocoTestReport
/opt/gradle/gradle-7.6/bin/gradle bootRun


This is my applications.properties in my gitlab project. The mariadb is running on my laptop, everything is running on the same device, gitbash > terraform > debian. they have mariadb installed, It communicates with the mariadb terminal.
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/trailsdb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=comsc
spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver

Quick fire things I've done to fix, but to no avail.

Rechecked and granted permissions for 'root' user
did a manual connection test but it was fineManual connection test
checked if port 3306 is being listened too (it was fine)
enter image description here
I sent my laptop in to school IT and they said the firewall isn't the issue.
checked my openstack security group and allowed port ranges 22, 443, 80, 3306 and 8080 so sql should be allowed through openstack
The entire pipeline is running on this laptop, so MariaDB and jenkins. lOCALHOST should be fine(?)
Attempted many many terraform destroys and rebuilds and various terraform script adjustments to see if anything worked.
changed the gitlab applications.properties from mariadb to mysql but it gave the same result.

I want Jenkins to build the website project, with the database connected to or created if it cant find it.
